# Getting error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target" in Concat function

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I was trying to duplicate the array using the `concat` function, but I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

My code:

```
let duplication = ([1,2,3,4,5]) => {this.concat(this)};
```

Comment: your code makes little sense. Array functions do not have this, why is the arguments an array?

Comment: Your code is broken in multiple ways. Please provide an example input with desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has many issues from an `this` is not your array. You are setting an array as an argument (which is what is generating that error)

This is basically what you were trying to do:

```js
var dupe = arr => arr.concat(arr)
console.log(dupe([1,2,3]))
console.log(dupe([1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a few options, I like to use the spread operator

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
var secondArray = [...arr]

console.log(arr)
console.log(secondArray)
```

But if you still want to use concat

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
// Call the concat function without any params
var secondArray = arr.concat()

console.log(arr)
console.log(secondArray)
```